# Retrieve table name

Tags: lua, key-value, lua-table

Is there a way to retrieve the name of a table? For example, from this table I want extract only the keys name "Mimic", "Molibdeno", "Tamarindo", "Wrenna"

```
UnitScanDB = {
    profiles = {
        Mimic = {
        ...
        },
        Molibdeno = {
        ...
        },
        Tamanrindo = {
        ...
        },
        Wrenna = {
        ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tables, like every other Lua value (including functions), do not have "names." You are asking for the field variable name (which is a table key of type "string" that happens to satisfy the requirements for a Lua identifier, which simplifies the syntax).  Therefore, the answers will be methods of finding keys in tables.

Answer (score 3):

You can [iterate](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.4.5) over the inner table using [`pairs`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-pairs):

```
for k in pairs(UnitScanDB.profiles) do
   -- handle k
end
```

Using the above loop, you could, for example, copy all of the keys into a new table:

```
local names = {}
for k in pairs(UnitScanDB.profiles) do
  table.insert(names, k)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply access those keys by their name, like so:

```
mimic = UnitScanDB.profiles.Mimic
molibdeno = UnitScanDB.profiles.Molibdeno
```